# Cassandra time series table design for timestamp range queries

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql

Our problem is a bit different from a usual timeseries problem as we do not have natural partition key in our data. In our system we get not more than 5k/s messages, so following many publications (like [this one](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling)) we figured out a following schema (it's more complex but the below matters most):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.messages (
    date TEXT,
    hour INT,
    createdAt TIMESTAMP,
    uuid UUID,
    data TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ((date, hour), createdAt, uuid)
)
```

We mostly want to query the system based on the creation (event) time; other filtering will likely be done on different engines like Spark. The problem is that we may have a query that spans e.g. two months, so ideally we should put 60+ dates and 24 hours in the WHERE-IN-part of query, which is cumbersome to say the least. Of course, we can execute queries like below:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE createdat >= '2017-03-01 00:00:00' LIMIT 10 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

My understanding is that, while the above works, it will make a full scan, which will be expensive on larger cluster. Or am I mistaken and C* knows, which partitions to scan?

I was thinking to add an index, but this problem likely falls into [high-cardinality antipattern](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-native-secondary-index-deep-dive), as I understand.

EDIT: the question is not that much about the data model, though suggestions are welcome, but more about feasibility of making the queries with `cratedat` range instead or listing all `date` and `hour` values required in WHERE-IN-part of query to avoid full scans.

Comment: At 5000 messages per second, if you issue a request for 2 months, and if each column takes 20 bytes (depends on the "data"), then you'll be looking at a 500 Gb result -- not very practical IMO, will cause problems on many levels.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but we know about the sizes and we cannot really do much about it; at the end we process data is Spark and currently we have such volumes, thus, it is not a major issue for us. In the full model there is a UUID component in the primery key and nothing is lost really. My question is more about efficient select without a full scan happening and, in general, using Cassandra in such data-warehouse-like setup.